# How to disable the floating window feature or floating application on android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm building a broswer app on android for school exams. now the application is able to minimize cheating because the application requires users to allow drawing over other apps. However, currently the application is still found to have loopholes, namely by using floating windows / floating apps. Is there a way to block or disable floating apps or floating windows on Android?

Comment: See: [Android detect or block floating/overlaying apps](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36923301/295004) and [How do apps detect that SAW permission is currently being used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66681440/295004)